# How to write Our own views in Django CMS?

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-cms, django-1.7

I am creating a blog website in Django CMS, I want to custom design the content management system and I have to add the custom url and views can any one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [app hooks](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html) to achieve this. Basically, this allows you to dynamically hook urls into your page tree. You can check out [aldryn-blog](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-blog) or [djangocms-blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog) for a few examples on how to do this.